# Is there a Jeff Atwood's User Friendly Exception Handling (Or Similar) for C# / Winforms .Net 3.5+?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

We have a .Net 3.5 C# / Winforms desktop application with a very limited size/scope/userbase (40 users). I need a way to gather more information about unhandled exceptions, but I don't believe I need anything as big or broad as the Microsoft Exception Handling Application Block*. I just need capture and send.

Is there an exception handler similar in scope and feature set to Jeff Atwood's "[User Friendly Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7482/User-Friendly-Exception-Handling)", for C# on a newer version of .Net? (in my case 3.5, but we eventually hope to move to 4+)

I would love to use ELMAH, but it doesn't work with Winforms.

Alternately, can Jeff Atwood's exception handling work with C# 3.5 / winforms?

*more precisely, I prefer Mr. Atwood's concise 2004 blog post describing his solution and its limited, but useful scope, over the broad and vague documentation of the other. We should all strive to explain components well enough that people are asking for them to be ported to another language 9 years later. ;-)

Comment: I like the fact it takes a screenshot! That would be very useful for investigation.

Comment: I found this similar one by Andy Searls (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24437/Automatic-Error-Handling), but ran into some issues targeting my platform, so thought I'd ask in case there was an obvious or better solution I was overlooking, before hacking away at it a while longer.

Comment: What about https://exceptionreporter.codeplex.com/ - Doesn't **require** V3.5 but obviously works with it.

Comment: sgmoore: I haven't seen that one before. Looking into it now. It does look like it's more about providing info to the end user rather than reporting back to the programmer though. I am ok with both, but mainly need reports back to the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up an unhandled exception handler, then log those exceptions out using a library like ELMAH but configurable from code, given you don't have a web.config.

We use: http://nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Exceptional/

Catching unhandled exceptions: http://mike.woelmer.com/2009/04/dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions-in-winforms/

Comment: That article is very helpful!

Comment: Does StackExchange.Exceptional work with traditional desktop Winforms? ELMAH is targeted towards web application, otherwise I would be using it. Have used it with great success on other projects.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using my own version of Jeff's code for years.  It works fine under every target I've ever tried.

Is there a reason you don't think it will work?

Just change the target and rebuild.

Comment: I am using C#. I suppose I could compile it to a DLL and drop it in my bin folder. Is that how you're using it or are you on VB?

Comment: There was as C# version in the comments of the original article.

Comment: Awesome! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I use NBug, which also provides exception handling hooks to unhandled exceptions. It works for console, WinForms, and WPF,

http://nbug.codeplex.com